# Как убрать промежуток у inline-block?

Tags: html, css

Есть три `li`. 
Им указанно `display: inline-block` и `margin-right: 19px`.

При этом еще добавляется `3px` (синий кружочек). Как убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609992/Отступы-между-элементами-с-inline-block/610041#610041

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить родителю `font-size:0`. Ну а деткам соответственно верный размер шрифта.

Comment: Объяснили бы попутно, почему именно font-size

Comment: "Как убрать?" (с)
Это ответ на вопрос. Если нужно объяснение - это нужно указать в вопросе.

Comment: По-моему это несколько противоречит сути SO.

Answer (score 2):

inline-block по сути является буквой/словом, по сему перенос строки или пробел между буквами создаст этот самый отступ

Самый верный вариант, по-моему, это не лезть в css с различными хаками, а воспользоваться комментариями. Примерно так:

```
<div>
        <div></div><!--
    --><div></div><!--
    --><div></div>
</div>
```

Тогда между элементами не будет ни символов пробела, ни переноса строки

Либо не переносите строку между этими элементами

```
<div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению список генерируется плагином. Вариант выше подходит лучше всего.

Answer (score 0):

Можно у родителя этих трех блоков выставить `display: table`, а у самих блоков - `display: table-cell`.
Тогда сами блоки станут одинаковыми по высоте и будут пытаться занять всю высоту родителя.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  display: table;
}

.child {
  width: 33%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child red"></div>
  <div class="child green"></div>
  <div class="child blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы наблюдаете инлайн отступы. Как же их исправить? Есть несколько вариантов:

**Вариант 1**

В разметке убираем переносы для кнопок.

```
<main>
  <button>Кнопка</button><button>Кнопка</button><button>Кнопка</button>
</main>
```

**Вариант 2**

На родителя ставим font-size: 0; а уже к button задаем нужный размер шрифта.

```
main {
  font-size: 0;
}

button {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

**Вариант 3**

Можно закомментировать конец и начало строки.

```
<main><!--
  --><button>Кнопка</button><!--
  --><button>Кнопка</button><!--
  --><button>Кнопка</button><!--
--></main>
```